# R documentation with foreign characters

Tags: r, translation, documentation

I'm writing a function documentation in other language (portuguese) and it seems that R doesn't recognize some letters. The word beside `nlin` and `ncol` should be "número" and this is what it shows:

[image]

How do I make R documentation recognize this word?

Edit: I'm adding my description and the function file.

```
DESCRIPTION FILE:
Package: RPortugues
Type: Package
Title: What the Package Does (Title Case)
Version: 0.1.0
Author: Who wrote it
Maintainer: The package maintainer <yourself@somewhere.net>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
    Use four spaces when indenting paragraphs within the Description.
License: What license is it under?
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 6.1.1
```

and my function creation file:

```
#' Matriz
#'
#'cria uma matriz a partir do conjunto de valores fornecido.
#'
#' @param dados um vetor de dados opcional (incluindo um vetor de lista ou expressao). Objetos R de classe nao atomica sao coagidos por as.vector e todos os atributos sao descartados.
#' @param nlin o número desejado de linhas.
#' @param ncol o número desejado de colunas.
#' @param porlin logico. Se FALSE (o padrao), a matriz e preenchida por colunas, caso contrario, a matriz e preenchida por linhas.
#' @param dimnomes Um atributo dimnames para a matriz: NULL ou uma lista de comprimento 2, fornecendo os nomes das linhas e colunas, respectivamente. Uma lista vazia e tratada como NULL e uma lista de comprimento um como nomes de linha. A lista pode ser nomeada e os nomes da lista serao usados como nomes para as dimensoes.
#'
#' @return
#' @export
#'
#' @examples mdat <- matriz(c(1,2,3, 11,12,13), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2"), c("C.1", "C.2", "C.3")))
#'
#'mdat

matriz <- function(dados = NA, nlin = 1, ncol = 1, porlin = FALSE,
                   dimnomes = NULL) {
  matrix(dados, nlin, ncol, porlin, dimnomes)
}
```

Comment: Have you specified utf-8 encoding in the DESCRIPTION file?

Comment: I was trying to fix but I can't find the problem. I just edited so you can see the function documentation and the description file as it is now.

Comment: Writing R Extensions sys "If a package has a specified encoding, you should run R CMD build etc in a locale using that encoding." Have you done so?

Comment: No, how do I run this encoding utf8? I'm not familiar with utf8 at all

Comment: Sorry, I can't help further. I carefully kept my package in ASCII encoding (even though my own name is not in ASCII).